# Why do my theme is not working in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to use a theme called "Phoxy - Photography" purchased in themeforest. People comment that it is working for them but it is not for me. I tried installing and reinstalling all plugins and I followed all their steps in 
https://foxthemes.helpscoutdocs.com/category/1330-01-start-with-phoxy without having any trouble, but whenever I view my site looks like in the picture:
[image: error sample]
Everything is in grey without any format.

Does anybody has any idea on what am I missing?

Comment: I think it is working well and data has been imported with the placeholder images. That may create some confusion. If you share your site URL I am able to check and tell you more about it.

Comment: Seems you can go for a Support Forum to get support from Theme Author.

Comment: did you try adding images to the slider? those gray images are placeholder or bg color of the slider

Comment: We cannot help you troubleshoot your site without code or at least a URL.  If you are using a premium theme you can and should get support from the theme's author, as Tristup noted.